# Strip all HTML from text in GUI in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, html, javascript, mediawiki, drupal

I work with Ubuntu 22.08.

I am migrating my website from one content management system to another (from MediaWiki to Drupal).

If I copy a MediaWiki article to Drupal, it won't be copied as plain text but with HTML with links etc.

I need some *in-between processing* that will make the pasted data to be pasted without HTML.

If I were to use Windows 10, I could use something in AutoHotkey (AHk) to strip out the HTML but in Ubuntu I don't know any such way.

Perhaps I could use JavaScript to select the text-area in which the text is pasted and to add an event handler that handles the pasting and strips all HTML each time text is pasted, but I doubt there is a readily available way to do it in JavaScript.

How to strip all HTML from copied text in GUI in Ubuntu?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy the HTML output" in your question? How, specifically, are you copying it?

Comment: I just copy the content of a MediaWiki article (the HTML output of the text with MediaWiki syntax).

Comment: I have edited the question to remove that part.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/mediawiki_api

Comment: @Gantendo I use MediaWiki all core, I don't install any non core modules or themes. I guess I'll just use some web application filter for stripping out HTML as can be found with Google.........

Comment: @jalal How, specifically, do you "just copy" the data? What are the exact steps you perform to "just copy" it?

Comment: I mark the text with the mouse and then press CTRL+C.

Comment: @jalal The rendered Web page in a browser window? The source in a a text editor?

Comment: @MDeBusk yes, it is in a browser window and the source is in the (MediaWiki) text editor.

Comment: @jalal So you bring the source up in the MediWwiki editor that's in a browser window? NOT the rendered Web page?

Comment: @jalal Does it look [like this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:MediaWiki_edit_interface#/media/File:Basic_MediaWiki_editor_without_toolbar.png)?

Comment: I don't bring the source in the MediaWiki text editor, rather, I bring the HTML output of that source as appears in an article page.

Comment: In the editor it looks like this, in the article, no, the article is just an article as parsed and rendered to an end-user.

Comment: So you bring the page up in a browser, copy the whole thing, and paste it into a text editor, and somehow, HTML code comes with it?